# What is the Cheapest way to build a proximity-aware led wall

Tags: led

I want to build a led wall pretty much like this one: 
[interactive led wall](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xriYUzJ9Ls)

What are the different approaches to detect the people passing by? Looking for an easy - unexpensive way to do it.

This led wall can be  mounted indoors, and leds / lights may be smaller as well as the whole led array size.

Thanks!

Comment: how far away do you want to detect people in front of the Project?

Comment: I'd say 50 cm is enough

Answer (score 4):

you could use photo-transistors with IR emitters to make a short distance proximity sensor. Instead of photo-transistors you could use PIR sensor or Ultra sonic sensor.

Comment: what is the minimum distance to trigger a PIR sensor, how does it work? is it sensitive to abrupt changes in illumination?

Thanks

Comment: PIR sensors detect IR And can be sensitive to abrupt light changes but it can be filtered out. Miniumum distance is dependent on the PIR sensor, but most will work right up to the lens(E.G. moving your hand past the lens).

Comment: maybe an array of these or similar would be better? http://www.sparkfun.com/products/242 10cm  to 80cm range

Comment: True, but they are not very cheap and I'd have to use a lesser amount of them.

Comment: that was an example IR sensor, and yes for $10 a piece it can get pricey, but that doesn't stop you from making your own with an IR photo-transistor and an IR emitter.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the LEDs as photodiodes, although this may be only a short-range effect. See [this page](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~jhan/ledtouch/index.html) for an interesting demo video.

Answer (score 1):

A hacked Kinect could make a good, cheap sensor for detecting people walking by.

Comment: ...for some definitions of "Cheap".  What would a Kinect do for this project that a webcam on the ceiling wouldn't do?

Comment: Depth perception

Comment: but if you mount the webcam on the ceiling, you've got proximity detection for the wall.

Comment: True, I guess it depends on what kind of effects you want. A PIR sensor would do for something, a Kinect for others

Answer (score 1):

You could use a webcam or other video feed and some manner of computer-vision for the tracking- to an extent it looks like thats what the folk in the link did.

One method of doing this would be to have the camera(s) placed at the top of the wall facing down, and then doing edge detection on the image; ignore spots of environmental edges (cracks in concrete); then looking for any dense concentration indicative of a human. You then map that location from screen coordinates to a point along the wall.

Comment: what makes you think so? it is not an easy task as illumination changes, even the one coming from the wall itself.

Comment: @dnul It's the way certain effects are centered on the head of passers by. It could just be that they chose to use an average human height for those effects, but I didn't get that sense from it. Could also be wrong, but a video feed would be the cheapest/easiest way of tracking folk.

Comment: I was not aware of the height sensitivity,thanks.
I was assuming there were some kind of proximity sensors placed on the same wall, maybe one every certain number leds. Also, I wonder, if you were true , where the camera/s would be placed?.

Answer (score 1):

A tiny, cheap variation could be made with an [8x8 LED matrix](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/760), Arduino and [Gameboy camera](http://sophiateam.undrgnd.free.fr/microcontroller/camera/index.html).
The Arduino would repeatedly read the camera, scale down the image and present graphics to the matrix.

Cheap and easy. Not as impressive as the wall in the video though.

Answer (score 1):

Use FETs as electrometers:

- [Inexpensive FET Electrometer Array](http://amasci.com/electrom/e-field2.html)
- [Array-Electrometer Exhibit: "Visible E-field Panel"](http://amasci.com/electrom/electrom.html)

[image]

[image]